# Improve Jump Search algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to implement Jump search algorithm . I see some of the tutorial website showing wrong implementation of Jump Search algorithm. Is my below Jump Search implementation in C# correct ? How can i improve or make it more efficient?

```
 public int JumpSearch( int [] arr, int key)
{
  int arr_size = arr.Length;
  int prev = 0;
  int step = (int) Math.Sqrt( array_size);
  while( arr [ step] <= key && step < array_size-1)
  {
    prev = step;
    step += (int) Math.Sqrt( array_size);
    
        if( step > array_size -1)
        {
            step =  array_size -1;
        }
  }
   for( int j = prev ; j <= step ; j++)
   {
       if( arr [ j ]  == key)
     {
       return j;
     }
   }
 return -1;
}
```

Comment: you will most likely get a better answer in the "Code Review" community.

Comment: But why? It is worse than binary search, and `Array.BinarySearch` is built in. If you want to check if it is correct, write a unit test that compares the result with the known-good BinarySearch on some random data. If you want to know the performance, add a stopwatch to the unit tests. Or even better, use benchmark.net.

Comment: Tested code with random data, it seems correct to me. But not sure if there is edge cases which might fail.Most website shows below pseudocode, which is failing when tried with random data.                                                                     while(array[end] <= key && end < size) {
      start = end;       end += sqrt(size);
      if(end > size - 1)
         end = size;    }

Comment: If you have tested many times with random data, as well as various edge cases, (all zero? all int.MinValue? groups of equal values?) you can be reasonably confident it is correct. But if there are no known problems with the posted code you should probably ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Looks like calling the function with an empty array will cause an index-out-of-bounds exception.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 logical flaws in your piece of code that can lead to `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception.

- The first one is the condition in the `while` loop: `arr[step] <= key && step < array_size-1`.
  You tried to access index `step` of the array, but you did not check if `step` is a valid index. Technically, you did check for that with `step < array_size-1`, but unfortunately, the check comes **after** the accessing.
  To prevent it, simply swap the 2 conditions: `step < array_size-1 && arr[step] <= key`.
- The second one: in the last `for` loop, your array accessing with index `j` does not have a validation whether `j` is a valid index. Technically, you had your `j` run from `0` to `step`, and I think you assumed that `step` is always valid thank to the reassignment in the `while` block: `if( step > array_size -1) { step =  array_size -1; }`. That's partially true. Yet, our execution flow might not go into the while block all the time. If it does not, `step` is not validated and might be an out-of-range value.
  There are 2 ways to fix this: introduce another check `if( step > array_size -1) { step =  array_size -1; }` right before the `for` loop; or, simply having the condition `j <= Math.Min(step, arr_size-1)` for the `for` loop.

Final version of the code:

```
public int JumpSearch(int[] arr, int key)
{
    int arr_size = arr.Length;
    int prev = 0;
    int step = (int)Math.Sqrt(arr_size);
    while (step < arr_size - 1 && arr[step] <= key)
    {
        prev = step;
        step += (int)Math.Sqrt(arr_size);
        if (step > arr_size - 1)
        {
            step = arr_size - 1;
        }
    }
    for (int j = prev; j <= Math.Min(step, arr_size-1); j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] == key)
        {
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```